Predictor variables vs control variables for power analyses in multiple regression G*Power
I am using GPower to get an idea of the sample size needed to detect a medium effect size in the second and third steps of a hierarchical multiple regression model.  To do this, GPower asks for the hypothesized correlation matrix.  My question is whether the correlation matrix should include all 5 variables, or just the two theoretically interesting variables. Any help will be much appreciated!
